# Sorting in a PHP array based on user defined preference

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have an php array of countries that I'm looking to sort into a certain order based on what our client has asked.

The array is currently fed through from our backend, which I have no control over, as the following:

```
        array(10) {
  ["AUD"]=>
  string(17) "Australian Dollar"
  ["GBP"]=>
  string(22) "British Pound Sterling"
  ["CAD"]=>
  string(15) "Canadian Dollar"
  ["DKK"]=>
  string(12) "Danish Krone"
  ["EUR"]=>
  string(4) "Euro"
  ["JPY"]=>
  string(12) "Japanese Yen"
  ["NOK"]=>
  string(15) "Norwegian Krone"
  ["RUB"]=>
  string(13) "Russian Ruble"
  ["SEK"]=>
  string(13) "Swedish Krona"
  ["USD"]=>
  string(9) "US Dollar"
}
```

I need to reorder this based on the client preference to be something like

```
        array(10) {
  ["GBP"]=>
  string(22) "British Pound Sterling"
  ["AUD"]=>
  string(17) "Australian Dollar"
  ["NOK"]=>
  string(15) "Norwegian Krone"
  ["RUB"]=>
  string(13) "Russian Ruble"
  ["USD"]=>
  string(9) "US Dollar"
  ["CAD"]=>
  string(15) "Canadian Dollar"
  ["DKK"]=>
  string(12) "Danish Krone"
  ["EUR"]=>
  string(4) "Euro"
  ["JPY"]=>
  string(12) "Japanese Yen"
  ["SEK"]=>
  string(13) "Swedish Krona"

}
```

The only way I could think to do it was a switch statement,

```
            $ordered_currencies = Array();
        ?>
        <?php foreach ($currencies as $_code => $_name): 
                switch ($_code) {
            case 'AUD':
            $ordered_currencies[0] = [$_code => $_name];
                break;
            case 'CAD':
            $ordered_currencies[1] = Array($_code => $_name);
                break;
            case 'GBP':
            $ordered_currencies[2] = Array($_code => $_name);
                break;
            case 'DKK':
            $ordered_currencies[3] = Array($_code => $_name);
                break;
            case 'EUR':
            $ordered_currencies[4] = Array($_code => $_name);
                break;
            case 'JPY':
            $ordered_currencies[5] = Array($_code => $_name);
                break;
            case 'RUB':
            $ordered_currencies[6] = Array($_code => $_name);
                break;
            case 'SEK':
            $ordered_currencies[7] = Array($_code => $_name);
                break;
            case 'USD':
            $ordered_currencies[8] = Array($_code => $_name);
                break;
        }
         endforeach; ?>
```

But that returns an array in the below format, which isn't what I need

```
 array(10) {
[0]=>
  array(1) {
    ["AUD"]=>
    string(17) "Australian Dollar"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(1) {
    ["GBP"]=>
    string(22) "British Pound Sterling"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(1) {
    ["CAD"]=>
    string(15) "Canadian Dollar"
  }
.....
```

Any ideas?

Comment: look up usort in the manual

Comment: How is client preference stored?

Comment: _“But that returns an array in the below format, which isn't what I need”_ - well you could simply transform it into what you need - by looping over that again, and pushing the elements into a new array. `$new = []; foreach($yourarray as $item) { $new[key($item)] = current($item); }` and done … (But a solution that stores the client preferences somewhere and then uses usort or similar would perhaps be preferable, if you don’t want it to be so terribly “static” as it is with your current hard-coded implementation.)

Comment: client preference is literally a piece of paper in front of me... it follows no particular order

Comment: I tried Usort, but couldn't get it to apply to my situation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store client preferences as array of currency codes and take values from `$currencies` in order of this preferences array:

```
$preferences = ['AUD', 'CAD', 'GBP'];
$sortedCurrencies = [];
foreach ($preferences as $preference) {
    $sortedCurrencies[$preference] = $currencies[$preference];
}
```